# Add mutiple file paths into one in shell script

Tags: python-3.x, string, bash, shell

I have not coded in bash or made shell scripts before. The following code is working for me now in a shell script. ashlar is a python library which does multiple image stitching and registration. My question is how can I write only one variable instead of `$c1 $c3 $c5 $c7` in the last line.
I have tried using + or cat but it didn't work.

```
for i in 1 3 5 7
do
 export ROOT_DIR=a/b/c/abcd_"$i"_123/
 export FILENAME_HEADER=a_b_c_40X_
 export WIDTH=5
 export HEIGHT=15
 export PIXEL_SIZE=0.1507
 export OVERLAP=0.1
 export LAYOUT=snake
 export DIRECTION=vertical
 export MAX_SHIFT=30
 export SIGMA=2
 export ALIGN_CHANNEL=4
 export OUTPUT_DIR=a/b/c/sample.ome.tiff

 export c"$i"="fileseries|""$ROOT_DIR""|pattern=""$FILENAME_HEADER"""$i"_F{series}.ome.tiff|width=""$WIDTH""|height=""$HEIGHT""|pixel_size=""$PIXEL_SIZE""|overlap=""$OVERLAP""|layout=""$LAYOUT""|direction=""$DIRECTION"
done

ashlar $c1 $c3 $c5 $c7 --flip-y --pyramid --maximum-shift $MAX_SHIFT --filter-sigma $SIGMA --align-channel $ALIGN_CHANNEL -o $OUTPUT_DIR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use numbered variables, use an array:

```bash
c=()
for i in 1 3 5 7
do
    export ROOT_DIR="a/b/c/abcd_${i}_123/"
    ...
    c+=( "fileseries|${ROOT_DIR}|pattern=${FILENAME_HEADER}${i}_F{series}.ome.tiff|width=${WIDTH}|height=${HEIGHT}|pixel_size=${PIXEL_SIZE}|overlap=${OVERLAP}|layout=${LAYOUT}|direction=${DIRECTION}" )
    #^^^ .............................................................................................................................................................................................. ^
done
```

Then

```bash
ashlar "${c[@]}" --flip-y --pyramid --maximum-shift "$MAX_SHIFT" --filter-sigma "$SIGMA" --align-channel "$ALIGN_CHANNEL" -o "$OUTPUT_DIR"
# .....^^^^^^^^^
```

Some notes:

- I'm using braces to delineate variables instead of multiple quotes. It's a style preference.
- not *all* variables need to be exported: only the ones that the `ashlar` program uses. you can just say `var=value` to use a *shell* variable.
- quote your variables. See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I didn't know where exactly should export and I had my doubts so just put it everywhere. Can you please explain where in general is export needed and `"${c[@]}"` is the syntax to call all the files? For the variables and quotes is this a better way `WIDTH=5
  HEIGHT=15
  PIXEL_SIZE=0.1507
  OVERLAP=0.1
  LAYOUT=snake
  DIRECTION=vertical
  export ROOT_DIR="a/b/c/abcd_${i}_123/"
  export FILENAME_HEADER="06012022_rescan_S1_40X_"
  export MAX_SHIFT=30
  export SIGMA=2
  export ALIGN_CHANNEL=4
  export OUTPUT_DIR="/a/s.ome.tiff"`